# Angular Animation

Tags: angular, firebase, animación

Intento recrear una animacion de los elementos al entrar en la pagina y al seguir los pasos en los ejemplos encontrados no consigo que ocurre. Si trabajo con datos ya incorporadas funciona pero si se trata de primero recoger los datos del servidor y crear la animacion no lo hace.
Aqui le presento el codigo en partes que funciona y que no.
Parte fija:

```
animations: [
trigger('pageAnimations', [
  transition(':enter', [
    query('.hero', [
      style({ opacity: 0, transform: 'translateX(-100px)' }),
      stagger(50, [
        animate('500ms 1500ms cubic-bezier(0.35, 0, 0.25, 1)',
          style({ opacity: 1, transform: 'none' }))
      ])
    ])
  ])
]),]
```

Añado animaciona al pagina:

```
 @HostBinding('@pageAnimations')
  public animatePage = true;
```

Recopilo datos de un archivo
Los datos:

```
export const HEROES: Hero[] = [
  { id: 11, name: 'Dr Nice' },
  { id: 12, name: 'Narco' },
  { id: 13, name: 'Bombasto' },
  { id: 14, name: 'Celeritas' },
  { id: 15, name: 'Magneta' },
  { id: 16, name: 'RubberMan' },
  { id: 17, name: 'Dynama' },
  { id: 18, name: 'Dr IQ' },
  { id: 19, name: 'Magma' },
  { id: 20, name: 'Tornado' }
];
```

Recopilo los datos:

```
get heroes() { return this._heroes; }
  private _heroes: Hero[] = [];
```

Y paso a la lista:

```
this._heroes = HEROES;
```

La Lista:

```
<ul class="heroes">
            <li *ngFor="let hero of heroes" class="hero">
                <div class="inner">
                    <span class="badge">{{ hero.id }}</span>
                    <span>{{ hero.name }}</span>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
```

Todo arriba menciponado funciona tal como deberia.
Y ahora forma de recoger datos de la base de datos:

```
async getBiAndProd(): Promise<void> {
    const yu = await this.bisrv.getProducts(this.biid);
    yu.docs.forEach((prod) => {
      const dane = prod.data() as Product;
      dane['prid'] = prod.id;
      PRODUCT.push(dane);
    })
  }
```

Recopilo los datos:

```
get products() { return this._productlist }
  public _productlist: Product[] = [];
```

Y paso a la lista:

```
this._productlist = PRODUCT;
```

La lista:

```
<ul class="heroes">
            <li *ngFor="let hero of products; let i = index" class="hero">
                <div class="inner">
                    <span class="badge">{{ i + 1 }}</span>
                    <span>{{ hero.prid }}</span>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
```

Las dos metodos son igual con diferencia en recopilar los datos. La primara funciona bien y la secunda aparace la lista sin la animacion. Que es mal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La solucion fue bastante sencilla, remover pageAnimation y añadir directamente a un div donde se demenuestran los datos y con setTimeOut retrasar la animacion hasta que se cargan los datos